# PlaceholderText is not accessible XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am new to XAML and WPF.

I am trying to add a placeholder to my textbox but I got this error: "The property 'PlaceholderText' was not found in type 'TextBox'" and "The member "PlaceholderText" is not recognized or is not accessible".

When I tried to type PlaceholderText, it didn't even show up in the auto-complete drop down list. "Header" has the problem.

I am using VS 2015 community and .NET Framework 4.5.2

Below is my code which I got it from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox#Examples

```
<Window x:Class="QuickGarbageSort.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyTestApp"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MyTestApp" Height="550" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="What's your name?"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,20,0,20">

            <TextBox x:Name="nameInput"
                        Header="Enter your name:" PlaceholderText="Name"
                        Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

            <Button Content="Hello button" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="greetingOutput"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation you got the code from is a documentation for [`Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox), this is the textbox control used in Universal Windows Applications. This has a property called [`PlaceholderText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_TextBox_PlaceholderText)

The WPF one is [`System.Windows.Controls.TextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx), this is different and doesn't have a `PlaceholderText` property. In order to have something like the UWP placeholder text in WPF, you have to implement it yourself or use a third party library which offers a control with this functionality.